# Ubuntu Dual NIC

Tags: 14.04, networking, server

I recently switched from Windows to Ubuntu. It was working in Windows with exact configuration. One NIC(enp2s0) is connected to LAN and other NIC(enp1s0) is connected to router with internet access.

```
enp2s0 -manually configured - 192.168.1.133 subnet 255.255.0.0 gateway -none
```

`enp1s0 - autoconfigured from router`

I want to receive UDP stream from 238.x.x.x using enp2s0 and the rest with enp1s0.

On Ubuntu route command show this

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp1s0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp2s0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.0.0     U     100    0        0 enp2s0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp1s0
```

As of now I can ping google.com. However I can't receive UDP streaming using enp2s0. How can I use both network interfaces?

```
enp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:e0:4c:68:06:92
      inet addr:192.168.1.8  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::2e0:4cff:fe68:692/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:5568 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:488 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:1620181 (1.6 MB)  TX bytes:77235 (77.2 KB)

enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:e0:4c:68:06:93
      inet addr:192.168.1.133  Bcast:192.168.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::2e0:4cff:fe68:693/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:10802 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:85 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:1882391 (1.8 MB)  TX bytes:11331 (11.3 KB)
```

If I disconnect enp1s0, I am able receive UDP stream.